# Low pass to high pass filter conversion

Tags: audio, analog, active-filter

Ripples from Mutable Instruments (open hardware) is a low pass 4th order filter. The schematic is found here https://mutable-instruments.net/modules/ripples/downloads/ripples_v40.pdf

Can I swap resistors and capacitors in the signal chain to create a high pass filter?
eg R10, C7 swapped with R8, C6

I would do this is Sallen and Key configuration but the inclusion of the OTA and VCA ICs makes me question what would be the right conversion.

Comment: Assuming the circuit worked as a LPF, and you can live with the change in input impedance, you can swap the input with the input cap ground connections.  NO idea why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Below shows a high pass sallen key filter on the left, and a low pass sallen key filter on the right. The resistors and capacitors are swapped. (Both high and low pass filters form a band pass). If you want to convert one sallen key configuration to the other, then swap resistors and caps

[image]
Source: